# RAILS 5: Appending an HTML anchor to rails route path helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a button that directs the user to another page:

`<%= link_to "Jacuzzis", applications_path, class: "dropdown-item"%>`

At the moment, this will lead the user to my 'applications' page, but there are many applications on this page. So I want to append the 'jacuzzis' id to the path variable so that the browser jumps to that section upon page load.

E.g instead of a GET request to: `/applications`, it's `/applications#jacuzzis`

I guess something like `<%= link_to "Jacuzzis", (applications_path + '#jacuzzis'), class: "dropdown-item"%>`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass the `:anchor` option to your path helper.

`<%= link_to "Jacuzzis", applications_path(anchor: 'jacuzzis'), class: "dropdown-item" %>`

Reference: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/85b533308f5ddcb9a59853bce38a113b66b13faa/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L172-L175

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in rails way

```
<%= link_to post_path(@comment.post, anchor: 'some-id'), class: "dropdown-item" %>
```

Hope this will help

Thanks